# Can you regularize building footprints in QGIS like you do in ArcGIS?

Tags: qgis-3, lidar

I'm using LiDAR data where I've extracted the "building" category and created a raster dataset. I've then 'polygonized' the raster to create a vector polygon shapefile of building fooptrints.

I'd like to eradicate/normalize the pixelated shape of the polygons. I can see that ArcGIS has a feature titled 'Regularize Building Footprint' in 3D analyst which seems to do exactly this. Is there a similar algorithm/feature in QGIS? If so, does anyone have a worked example I can follow?

Comment: In future (if funding is met) they will be Integrating PDAL into QGIS https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/crowdfunding/pointcloud-qgis/ which can answer your ask.